# KPackageKit stuck with ttf-mscorefonts-installer package

Tags: 11.04, dpkg, kubuntu

When I try to install any package or even apply updates, the installer try to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package at the end and fails with error:

> One of the selected packages failed to
>   install correctly. More information is
>   available in the detailed report.
>   subprocess installed post-installation
>   script returned error exit status 30

How can I get rid of this package or get it installed?
I have seen other similar questions here but non of them solved my problem.

running `sudo dpkg --configure-a` displays a dialog asking for the proxy and when I select  it shows again and again !!

---

**Note :**

The mentioned package gets installed by Wine but after I update wine I usually uninstall it because it messes up the fonts of the system.

Comment: Two possibilities: (1) gui doesn't work properly, so try using terminal to install (2)website for fonts cannot be reached, so try again later.

Comment: @Jasper, updates installed successfully today and it did not try to install the fonts package. The problem seem to be gone now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is part of `kubuntu-restricted-extras` so in case you have that installed, `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` will be installed. And this package is not a stand-alone package, so during installation, it downloads the restricted Microsoft fonts from the SourceForge servers, so you got to have network connection to install the package even if it is already in your package cache.

While you've mentioned that this package messes up fonts appearance of your Wine apps, I haven't used Wine lately, but [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=195849) thread appears to have a solution to change fonts used for Wine applications, while it has solution targeted for Ubuntu, it should be applicable for Kubuntu as well.

Comment: Thanks @Kush for your reply. The package messes up the fonts of the system not wine apps. I mean even fonts inside web browsers look different. Also I am always connected to the internet so why does it fail to install ?

Comment: Make sure you use default fonts as system wide fonts (ubuntu with size 11 or so), and see if fonts now appear properly or not. While `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is not installing even after proper internet connection might be due to variety of reasons (DNS cannot resolve the address, etc). You may try re-downloading and re-installing the package after cleaning KPackageKit's cache and see if that works.

Comment: I got update notification today and it installed successfully but it did not install the package I mentioned. I do not know what happened but the problem seem to be gone now. May be it was a connection problem as you and Jasper said. Thank you very much for your help Kush.